# Error with PAR module

Tags: perl

I have been trying to build .exe through PAR in **windows XP** and
my perl version is **5.8.8**.. I installed the latest PAR from PPM

I gave the following command in the command prompt,

C:\Documents and Settings\abc\Desktop\serial>pp -o serial.exe serial.pl

**Set up gcc environment - 3.4.4 (cygming special, gdc 0.12, using dmd 0.125)

Program too big to fit in memory

Access is denied.**

Also it throws me the following error popup..
**C:\DOCUME~1\abc\LOCALS~1\Temp\parlLoYJMpa.exe is not a valid Win32 application.**

Actually my script in just one line code..
I am confused...
Please help me....

Comment: What is the one line, I'm using winxp ActiveState Perl 5.8.8 myself, perhaps I can try it.  My pp --version says "PAR Packager, version 0.982 (PAR version 0.984)"

Comment: print"hello"; is my one line code. I was just testing the PP.. it gives the above error

Comment: Consider upgrading both your perl and your PAR (and PAR::Packer) versions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Worked fine for me, but then I use pp all the time with no problem.  I didn't get any "Set up gcc environment..." message, no messages at all.  I'm putting this as an answer because not enough room in the comment for all this:

I did a gcc -v and got:

```
C:\tools\perl\tests>gcc -v
Reading specs from c:/Perl/site/lib/auto/MinGW/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/3.4.5/spec
s
Configured with: ../gcc-3.4.5-20060117-3/configure --with-gcc --with-gnu-ld 
--with-gnu-as --host=mingw32 --target=mingw32 --prefix=/mingw --enable-threads 
--disable-nls --enable-languages=c,c++,f77,ada,objc,java --disable-win32-registry 
--disable-shared --enable-sjlj-exceptions --enable-libgcj --disable-java-awt 
--without-x --enable-java-gc=boehm --disable-libgcj-debug --enable-interpreter 
--enable-hash-synchronization --enable-libstdcxx-debug
Thread model: win32
gcc version 3.4.5 (mingw-vista special r3)
```

Comment: I got this following when i typed.
C:\>gcc -v
Reading specs from /usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-cygwin/3.4.4/specs

Comment: Thread model: posix
gcc version 3.4.4 (cygming special, gdc 0.12, using dmd 0.125)